# How can I count boolean value from JSON response in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

How can I count Boolean value from JSON response?. I made firstly total message count and then use if statement to get only false values.

- I want only false values to be counted. 
  Count of `messageReaded = false`

Code:

```
let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
if response.isSuccess == true {

    self.AppMsg = response.messageList ?? []
    let msgCount = String(describing: self.AppMsg.count)

    if msgCount.isEmpty == false {
        for i in response.messageList ?? [] {
            if i.messageReaded == false {

            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "messageList": [
    {
      "messageId": 22,
      "messageReaded": false,
      "messageDate": "27.05.2020 07:01",
      "title": "New Message",
      "messageTypeCode": 1
    },
    {
      "messageId": 21,
      "messageReaded": true,
      "messageDate": "19.05.2020 07:00",
      "title": "Old Message",
      "messageTypeCode": 1
    }
  ],
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "İşlem Başarılı.",
  "statusCode": 1
}
```

Comment: Looks like you wrote working code already, what is the question?

Comment: @vpoltave I need to count boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the messages with condition `messageReaded == false` and `count` the result.

```
let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
if response.isSuccess {
    self.AppMsg = response.messageList ?? [] 

    let unreadCount = self.AppMsg.filter{$0.messageReaded == false}.count
}
```

It's not necessary to check if an array is empty before being iterated. If the array is empty the loop will be skipped.